# VBA: pull a value from an html span

Tags: vba

I am sure this has been answered, but I think I might not know how to ask the question correctly, so any help that either points me in the right direction and/or answers the question would be greatly appreciated.

I am attempting to pull a value out of a google search for weather.  The page has the code:

```
 <span class="wob_t" id="wob_tm" style="display: inline;">60</span>
```

What I want to get is the value "60".  The code I am working with is:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate ("https://www.google.com/#q=weather+little+rock")
While ie.busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Set iedoc = ie.document
temp = iedoc.getElementById("wob_tm").Value
```

Please and thanks!

Comment: Thanks for helping with the editing.  How do you do the code block?

Comment: iedoc.getelementbyid("wob_tm").innertext

Comment: Perfect!  thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iedoc.getelementbyid("wob_tm").innertext
```